# Как эмулировать запрос к сайту в программе?

Tags: c#

В программе пользователь должен вводить id и должен открываться сайт с нужным делом.

Вот этот сайт - [ссылка](https://kad.arbitr.ru/)

Как эмулировать на сайте, то что пользователь вводит id?

Comment: Отправить сереверу нужный POST запрос, такой же как браузер отправляет

Comment: На адрес /Kad/SearchInstances отправляется POST запрос в виде обычного JSON, например номер дела "123", то JSON будет:  {"Page":1,"Count":10,"Courts":[],"DateFrom":null,"DateTo":null,"Sides":[],"Judges":[],"CaseNumbers":["123"],"WithVKSInstances":false,"Cases":["123"]}  
Попробуйте запросить с помощью curl --data-binary  (curl - утилита)

Comment: @Blackmeser как сложно...

Comment: Вы взялись копать не имея понятия, что такое лопата, конечно это сложно. Почитайте про HTTP, как это работает, для начала. Узнайте, что есть GET и POST запросы, и как они работают, узнайте, как посмотреть эти запросы в браузере. Узнайте, что такое HTTP заголовки, какие они бывают, за что отвечают. Узнайте, что такое JavaScript и о том, что он может изменять разметку страницы и сам отправлять запросы. И только потом можно уже со знанием дела начинать парсить.

Comment: Можно еще через Selenium Web Driver, но это точно не та задача, где его нужно применять